# Google Maps JavaScript API - Display Zip Code instead of United States

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

how can I show the address including zipcode on the same textbox? For example: 123 main st, Atlanta, GA 30305.
This is what I have:
    
     
         //[how to get google places autocomplete to work if the textbox is initially hidden and should be shown only after a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119358/how-to-get-google-places-autocomplete-to-work-if-the-textbox-is-initially-hidden)

```
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
     prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
     function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
     }
     // fires after the partial update of UpdatePanel
     function EndRequest(sender, args) {
         initialize();
     }
    function initialize() {
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.847037, -84.393539));
        var origin_input = document.getElementById('saddr');
        var options = {
            bounds: defaultBounds,
            types: ['address'],//Addresses only
            componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' }};
        var autocomplete_origin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input, options);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function updateAddressField()
    {
        var addrs = document.getElementById('saddr').value;
        document.getElementById('hdnAddress').value = addrs;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't know what kind of textbox you are talking about, but if you want to obtain zip code via auto complete, here's your answer:

[**Link**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Comment: I am talking about the textbox that says: Enter your address. I know how to get the zip after selecting an address.

Comment: So when you start entering the address, the addresses shown by google do not have the zip code. There is provably a parameter in var options = {...} that will show the zip code. Thank you for your response